# What should go into procfile for pinky stack on CloudControl

Tags: cloudcontrol, procfile

We have been using the luigi stack on CloudControl for our PHP application, with web and worker roles, and we would like to migrate to the pinky stack.

The latter seems to require the use of procfile in order to define launch commands for web and worker, and we can't seem to figure out what those should be.

Could someone provide a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the pinky stack there is a default Procfile generated by the buildpack. You only need to override the default Procfile when you want to start some workers, were you also need to define the web process to start.

You can fine more info at 
https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php#custom-procfile.

The command to add the worker also needs to be modified, see https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Data%20Processing/Worker.